# Rounded corners on triangle in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm trying to make a triangle that has rounded corners. The triangle will look like this:

[image]

The bottom left corner is the only one that seems fairly easy to make, mostly because that is a 90 degree 'turn'. That turn is made using the `Q` command in SVG with the following parameters:

`Q x,y + height, x, y + height - RADIUS` starting at the right bit of the arc I'm creating.

However, the other corners are variable, depending on the triangle size. I can calculate their angles using `atan()` functions, but I have no clue how to implement them. I would like it to follow the RADIUS variable (5 in this case).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you only need this for right angle triangles with sides parallel to basic axes, this makes things a bit easier.

As you've said, the right angle is easy.

For other angles, you need to calculate centers of the circles. Let's say `w` and `h` are width and height of the triangle. Let's also say `x, y` are the coordinates of the rightmost node. The center of the rightmost triangle is: `x - r * h / w, y - r`. The angle that's covered by the arc you need to draw is `π - α`, where `α` is the corner angle you've calculated with `atan`.

Topmost corner will be handled similarly.

This should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `a` command I can make very detailed corners with a certain `rX` and `rY`. I would call the function like:

`a 5 5 0 0 1 0 5 5`, and it will make a circle with radius 5 and `dX = 5` and `dY = 5`. Which is perfect.

The radius is ideal at 90 degrees, so when I have a 50 degree corner I just use `(50 / 90) * RADIUS` for the values, and it's perfect.